# Setting foreground color works only once for NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

The phone part of the string gets the underline attribute, but the color remains red. I've separated the color and underline `setAttributes()` calls, to make things clear, the same happens when it's one call.

```
    let text = "call "
    let phone = "1800-800-900"

    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text + phone, attributes: nil)
    let rangeText = (attrString.string as NSString).range(of: text)
    let rangePhone = (attrString.string as NSString).range(of: phone)

    attrString.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red],
                             range: rangeText)

    attrString.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue],
                             range: rangePhone)

    attrString.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue],
                             range: rangePhone)
```

Comment: Use `addAttributes()` instead of `setAttributes()`. But I'd suggest to create two `NSAttributedString`, one for `text` and another for `phone` and then append them. Why? Because if `text` contains `phone` (well, in your case it may rarely be it), but `range(of:)` returns the first occurence, so you may encounter issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the doc of [`setAttributes()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1414304-addattributes):

> These new attributes replace any attributes previously associated with
>   the characters in aRange.

So in other words, it replace them, erasing all previously set, so when you add the underline, it removes the color at that range.

Solution, use `addAttributes()` instead of `setAttributes()`:

```
let text = "call "
let phone = "1800-800-900"

let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text + phone, attributes: nil)
let rangeText = (attrString.string as NSString).range(of: text)
let rangePhone = (attrString.string as NSString).range(of: phone)

attrString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red],
                         range: rangeText)

attrString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue],
                         range: rangePhone)

attrString.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue],
                         range: rangePhone)
```

Other solution, use two `NSAttributedString` (I also remove the `NSAttributedStringKey` in the enum)

```
let textAttrStr = NSAttributedString(string:text, attributes:[.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
let phoneAttrStr = NSAttributedString(string:phone, attributes:[.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
                                                               .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue])

let finalAttrStr = NSMutableAttributedString.init(attributedString: textAttrStr)
finalAttrStr.append(phoneAttrStr)
```

Possible issue with the first solution:
`range(of:)` returns the range of the first occurence only.
In other words, if text = "1800 " and phone = "18", you'll get unwanted results. because `rangePhone` would be from index 0 to 1, and not 7 to 8 in `1800 18`. This issue won't happen in the second one.

Comment: I've tried both of the code snippets you suggested, I get the same result as before. the phone text remains red.

Comment: I tried the code in PlayGround, and got not issue, "call 1800-800-900", where "call" is red, and the number is underlined and blue. You may have another place where you set red color.

Answer (score 0):

You **should not separate** the second and the third call of `setAttributes`, since the latter will overwrite the earlier. Combine the styles in one array:

```
attrString.setAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
                          .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue],
                          range: rangePhone)
```

**Result:**

[image: screenshot of the result]