# How do I make NSMutableAttributedString work for links?

Tags: swift, hyperlink, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm using `NSMutableAttributedString` to format text strings. It works fine, even with the links. But for some reason the font size for the links won't change even though I have specified the size. My function looks like this: (There are comments in the code to explain everything)

```
func formatfunc2(chapter: String, boldStart: Int, boldLength: Int, italicsStart: Int, italicsLength: Int, link: [String], linkStart: [Int], linkEnd: [Int]) -> NSAttributedString {

    let bold = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
    let italics = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 17)

    //BELOW IS MY FORMAT FOR THE HYPERLINK
    let hyperlink = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: chapter, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)])

    //BELOW ARE FORMAT FOR BOLD AND ITALICS - AND THEY WORK FINE
    attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: bold, range: NSRange.init(location: boldStart, length: boldLength))
    attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: italics, range: NSRange.init(location: italicsStart, length: italicsLength))

    //THE LOOP GOES THROUGH ALL LINK ADRESSES AND THEIR POSITIONS
    for i in 0...link.count - 1 {

        //HERE I ADD THE FONT SIZE TO THE SAME POSITION AS THE LINKS, BUT IT DOESN'T WORK 
        attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: hyperlink, range: NSRange.init(location: linkStart[i], length: linkEnd[i]))

        let url = URL(string: link[i]) as! URL

        //MY THEORY IS THAT THE CODE BELOW OVERRIDES THE PREVIOUS FONT SIZE
        attributedString.setAttributes([.link: url], range: NSMakeRange(linkStart[i], linkEnd[i]))
    }

    return attributedString
}
```

So the format works fine for all other text but not for the `links`. Can I add font size in the last code part instead? :

```
attributedString.setAttributes([.link: url], range: NSMakeRange(linkStart[i], linkEnd[i]))
```

Comment: It's because you are doing `attributedString.setAttributes()` instead of `attributedString.addAttributes()`. Because it's a `set` and not a `add`, it replace all the previous attributes (the fond one).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting foreground color works only once for NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318561/setting-foreground-color-works-only-once-for-nsattributedstring)